# Equivalence of rational Voevodsky motives: partial Converse to Conjecture of Orlov

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, noncommutative-geometry, motives

There is a conjecture of Orlov stating that if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective complex varieties that are derived equivalent (equivalent bounded derived categories of coherent sheaves), then their rational Voevodsky motives $M(X)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $M(Y)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ are equivalent.

My question is whether the equivalence of $M(X)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $M(Y)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ implies the partial converse that the rational(!) bounded derived categories of coherent sheaves are equivalent? There is a result of Cisinski and Tabuada that implies that the equivalence of the rational Voevodsky motives implies that the noncommutative rational motives of $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent in Kontsevich's category of rational noncommutative motives.

Comment: What is the rational bounded derived category (as opposed to the usual one?)

Comment: A comment on the relation between Sasha's answer and the theorem of Cisinski and Tabuada: in the example Sasha gave, there are semiorthogonal decompositions of the derived categories. These imply that the noncommutative motives split like the ordinary motives do (which gives the equivalence of noncommutative motives). But semiorthogonal decompositions are far from giving equivalences of derived categories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely not. Take $X$ to be the blowup of $P^2$ at a point and $Y$ to be $P^1 \times P^1$. Then
$$
M(X) = 1 + 2L + L^2 = M(Y),
$$
but the derived categories are different, since both varieties are Fano and non-isomorphic,

Comment: Even the rational bounded derived categories are different? By rational, I mean you rationalize the triangulated category.

Comment: @user114292 In what sense do you rationalize?

Comment: By this, I mean you take the triangulated category, and you do Verdier quotient so that $Cone(E\xrightarrow{n\cdot id_E} E)\simeq 0$ for every object $E$ and every nonzero integer $n$.

Comment: @user114292 If everything is over a field of zero characteristic this cone is already zero, so your operation changes nothing.

Comment: And if the characteristic of the field is positive then this operation kills everything.:)

Comment: However, do you want to consider certain rational homotopy types of these bounded derived categories? Then you should specify some model category containing them as objects.